# How can i concat Year, day, Hour and minute of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I had a Dataframe with this kind of date

| Year | Day | Hour | Minute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 244 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017 | 244 | 0 | 1 |
| 2017 | 244 | 0 | 2 |

I want to create a new column on this DataFrame showing the date +hour minute but I don't know how to convert the days into months and unify everything

I try something using pd.to_datetime like the code below.

```
line['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(line['Year'] + line['Day'] + line['Hour'] + line['Minute'], format= '%Y%m%d %H%M')
```

I would like to have something like this:

| Year | Month | Day | Hour | Minute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 9 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017 | 9 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2017 | 9 | 1 | 0 | 2 |

Comment: I believe you can use %j as day of the year as a zero-padded decimal number.  or %-j as day of the year as a decimal number.  https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your case do

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.astype(str).agg(' '.join,1),format='%Y %j %H %M')
Out[294]: 
0   2017-09-01 00:00:00
1   2017-09-01 00:01:00
2   2017-09-01 00:02:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]

#df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
#df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
```

Comment: I think this is the nearest solution to my case, but I tried to put this on the code and it's not working, the new column was not created, is this supposed to solve the creation of the new column?  or I mess with the code? 
```
 line['date'] = pd.to_datetime(line.astype(str).agg(''.join,1), format= '%Y %j %H %M')
```

Anyway thanks for all the Help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format='%Y') \
    + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['Day']-1, unit='D')
print(s)

# Output
0   2017-09-01
1   2017-09-01
2   2017-09-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now you can insert your columns:

```
df.insert(1, 'Month', s.dt.month)
df['Day'] = s.dt.day
print(df)

# Output
   Year  Month  Day  Hour  Minute
0  2017      9    1     0       0
1  2017      9    1     0       1
2  2017      9    1     0       2
```

Comment: @MiguelRibeiroGodoy. Does something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Month"]=round(df["Day"]/30+.5).astype(int)
```

This establishes a new column and populates taht column by using the day column to calculate the month (total days / 30), rounding up by adding .5 and inserting it as an integer using `astype`

**Example screenshot**

[image: data frame example]